# Minimum distance between Minecraft job blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am creating my own village in Minecraft and ran into some questions while following the village blueprints from the wiki. There are multiple buildings that have several duplicate job site blocks (leatherworker has 4 cauldrons, fisherman has 2 barrels, etc). I am curious whether this would mean that multiple villagers would share the same building (ie. 4 leatherworkers) **or** if there is a minimum distance between job blocks? Since the vanilla buildings have these duplicate blocks, it seems as if there must be some way to avoid having multiple people using the same building, but I'm not sure how.

As you can see in this image, the tannery has 4 cauldrons in the vanilla build. However, I **do not want** to have 4 leatherworkers in the town; I only want one. Is there anyway to keep the 4 cauldrons while only having one leatherworker, or do I need to remove all the extra cauldrons to limit the number of workers there? How do vanilla villages handle this (*or if they kept breeding, would they eventually have 4 leatherworkers*)?

[image: Tannery Blueprint]

TL;DR: Will having multiple job blocks in a village building (as seen in vanilla buildings) cause multiple villagers to use the building?

Answer (score 1):

If you want villagers in different houses you just have to have a job site blocks in different houses. Though if you want them together you can have the blocks as close together as you want. Just make sure the villager can reach the block.

Comment: Hi, I think I may have been a bit unclear in the original question; my aplogies. I have included an example and emphasized that I only want one leatherworker in the town (but the vanilla building has 4 cauldrons), and am wondering if there's anything in place to handle this.

Comment: Oh! It's alright. If you want one leatherworker you have to have only one cauldron to prevent other villagers to take the same job unfortunately.

Comment: But if you want to keep the cauldrons you can give the other villagers other jobs first. The comment above only accounts for unemployed villagers.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely true, however, since the villagers can breed on their own (with farmers handing out food) I would need to indefinitely keep other job blocks available and closer...a little more involved than I wanted to be. I'm not surprised that there's no way to do this (as you mentioned in the second comment), but I was hoping there would be since it was following the default village layouts. I guess these layouts must rely on not being loaded frequently or already having most villagers assigned to jobs?

Comment: What about this: 1. Box the farmer inside an area with a bed and a compostor (so he wont get mad at you for removing access to his home and job block). Doing this will cut him off from sharing food thus stopping reproduction. 2. When you wan't a new villager. Destroy all cauldrons but the one the leatherworker is using (so when the baby villagers grow up they can't be leatherworkers.) 3. Once the grown baby villagers grow up you can put the cauldrons back as normal. Just make sure you box the farmer back in.

Comment: The famer can be used as a reproduction On and Off switch in other words.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point, definitely better than removing the farmer entirely. I'll probably just go with removing the extra cauldrons (and barrels, etc) from within the village radius just to make the village more autonomous. Thanks for the info though!